# Formula for getting Roll, Pitch and Yaw values from MPU-9150 raw data

Tags: arduino, sensors, gyroscope

I am a newbie in MPU9150 9-axis IMU sensor, working on a project in which the Roll, pitch and Yaw value will be showed in a GUI. I have used the code from here: https://github.com/jrowberg/i2cdevlib/tree/master/Arduino/MPU9150
The problem is, as in GUI I will show the 3D representation of the roll, pitch and yaw. What will be the specific conversion formula from the raw data?

my WHO_AM_I resistor value: 0x68,

Accelerometer configured : 2g ,

Gyroscope configured: 250 dps,

Any help will be GREAT. Thanks in advance!

Comment: doing the same thing. have one question, are you getting yaw pitch roll values? in my case they are changing so quickly like: -50,  60, 32 -65 etc (that was for yaw value)

Comment: @maximus yes I am getting pitch and roll values using Euclidean formula, I got help from this article: http://www.geekmomprojects.com/gyroscopes-and-accelerometers-on-a-chip/ and I will add the answer here very soon.

Comment: Sorry for offtop, have you had such a problem when data the MPU was working for a few seconds fast enough, but after a few seconds after the start it slows down so much? Experiencing such a problem now.

Comment: not sure but checking your baud rate in the serial monitor as well as arduino code can lead you to identify your problem. Many people face this kind of problem only for mismatching the baud rate. @maximus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In java,

```
    float alpha=(float) 0.5;
    double fXg=0.0,fYg=0.0,fZg=0.0;
    fXg = xx * alpha + (fXg * (1.0 - alpha));
    fYg = yy * alpha + (fYg * (1.0 - alpha));
    fZg = zz * alpha + (fZg * (1.0 - alpha));

    //Roll,Pitch & Yaw Equations
   double roll  = (Math.atan2(-fYg, fZg)*180.0)/3.14;
   double pitch =( Math.atan2(fXg, Math.sqrt(fYg*fYg + fZg*fZg))*180.0)/3.14;
   double yaw = 180 * Math.atan (fZg/Math.sqrt(fXg*fXg + fZg*fZg))/3.14;
```